# data variable not being updated from watcher on computed property in Vue.js with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vuex, vue.js, vuejs2

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjvu6bn7/

I have a watcher on a computed property, which has a dependency on Vuex store variable, which is being set asynchronously. I am trying to set data variable of Vue component, when this computed property is changing, but this is not happening.

Here is Vue component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data : {
        myVar : ""

  },
  beforeMount() {
        this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_PETS', {
        }).then(() => {
                    console.log("fetched pets")
        })

  },
  computed:{
      pets(){
        return this.$store.state.pets
      }
    },
  watch:{
    pets: (pets) => {
      console.log("Inside watcher")
      this.myVar = "Hey"
    }
  }
});
```

Here is Vuex store:

```
const state = {
  pets: []
};

const mutations = {
  SET_PETS (state, response) {
        console.log("SET_PETS")
    state.pets = response;
  }
};

const actions = {
 FETCH_PETS: (state) => {
      setTimeout(function() { 
            state.commit('SET_PETS', ['t7m12qbvb/apple_9', '6pat9znxz/1448127928_kiwi'])
    }, 1000)
 }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mjvu6bn7/) is fiddle created for this. As you can see, myVar is not being updated, however watcher gets called when pets get loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the fact that ES6 arrow functions [do not bind the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (arrow functions aren't simply syntactic sugar over a regular `function`). So in your example, `this` inside the `pets` watcher defaults to `window` and `myVar` on the Vue instance is never set. If you change your code as follows, it works fine:

```
watch: {
    pets(pets) {
        console.log("Inside watcher")
        this.myVar = "Hey"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because this is not what you expect in the inner function.

Try this:

```
watch:{
    var that = this;
    pets: (pets) => {
      console.log("Inside watcher")
      that.myVar = "Hey"
    }
```

Comment: That's actually a syntax error - you can't put variable declarations inside object literals.